# Как дать доступ к записи через пароль JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Пишу школьный проект - программа для шифрования.
В таблице TableView есть записи, на которых стоит пароль, т.е. есть кнопки, которые для изменения одних записей требуют пароль. 
Дк вот, при нажатии на кнопку редактировать запись у меня вызывается метод, который открывает окно ввода пароля.
После вызова этого метода сразу идёт условие, которое как раз проверяет правильно ли введён пароль или нет.
Проблема в том, что метод то окно открывает, а само условие ввода пароля не дожидается и поэтому при выполняется до ввода пароля, а значит дает false и не выполняет необходимое редактирование даже при правильном пароле.
примерно так:

```
void method() {
    //тут при вводе пароля переменной correct присваивается значение true
    checkPassword();
    if (correct == true) {
        profilesTable.getSelectedItem().setText(textField.getText());
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста, буду рад любой помощи)

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить, что checkPassword не меняет значение correct. Возможно зона видимости этой переменной ограничена. Временно в разных кусках когда можно для отладки сделать System.out.println (correct); и смотреть на условия.

Comment: В том то и дело что correct  меняется. Я использую в качестве диалогового окна  JFXDialog из сторонней библиотеки JFoenix скорей всего он открывает новую панель дк вот метод открывает новую панель но он же не будет ждать пока сработает слушатель кнопки он продолжит выполнять программу а продолжать программу это и есть условие при котором correct пока что false

Answer (score 0):

В итоге получилось, что я начал в метод checkPassword() передавать номер функции и через switch() выполнять тот самый метод, который и вызвал проверку пароля.
Всё прекрасно работает.